# How to delete custom properties from .blend file?

Tags: python

Execution of this code will write in .blend file structure `Aaa` with data `bb == True`.

```
class Aaa(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    bb: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)
bpy.utils.register_class(Aaa)

bpy.types.Scene.aa = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Aaa)
bpy.context.scene.aa.bb = True

del bpy.types.Scene.aa

bpy.types.Scene.aa = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Aaa)
print(bpy.context.scene.aa.bb)
```

How to delete this data from the .blend file if `del bpy.types.Scene.aa` removes only the api-defined by which they are read?

And how do I make sure that data with this structure is guaranteed to be missing in .blend file?

Comment: `bpy.ops.wm.properties_remove(data_path = 'scene', property_name = 'aa')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pop a custom property

```
import bpy

class Aaa(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    bb: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)
bpy.utils.register_class(Aaa)

bpy.types.Scene.aa = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Aaa)
bpy.context.scene.aa.bb = True

del bpy.types.Scene.aa

bpy.context.scene.pop("aa")

print(hasattr(bpy.context.scene, "aa"))
print("aa" in bpy.context.scene)
```

```
output:
False
False
```

You can make sure the property is removed from
`Outliner`

[image]

**Please note** that the UI will not update immediately after running the code, you will need to switch to a different tab and switch back manually.

Answer (score 2):

`del bpy.types.Scene.aa` will remove the "API defined" flag on the property and it will prevent any new scene to mandatorily get this property assigned, but it won't remove it from scenes which already had it assigned. You can delete it with `del scene["aa"]`

Something like

```
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    if "aa" in scene:
        del scene["aa"]
```